# Help plotting lat and long coordinates

Tags: mapinfo, latitude-longitude

I have a set of lat and long coordinates whihc i have uploaded to be a table in mapinfo (the latest one) as you can tell i'm not much of a GIS wizz. I can't seemingly plot these coordinates in London they always plot in the sea somewhere below the ivory coast - this means my longitude is correct but my latitude isn't. However, coordinates exactly the same had been plotted by my colleague before,on the same layer successfully in london. Is there something i'm missing? Here is an example coordinate: 51.475566    -0.201027

Comment: it's possible that you have your projection set to web mercator (or something projected) and thus the lat/lon pairs end up near Null Island.

Comment: This will be an iant has said related to coordinate reference system -- almost certainly Web Mercator, which makes all lat/lons appear in sea off West coast of Africa. Make sure you have your project properties set to lat/lon.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mixed lat (y) and lon (x)? 
For London: 
Latitude (y) : 51.5085300
Longitude (x): -0.1257400

Comment: That will not be the reason -- 0 , 51 is off the coast of Somalia. This is to do with projections, and the fact that in web mercator, any lat/lon appears to be just off the coast of Ghana, as this is the point 0, 0.